# Sending JSON String through http.post on REST API

Tags: string, rest, api, post, controller

I am having some trouble sending a JSON String through a http.post to the backend. I am working on a project that it already has its structure and everything.

I created a PaymentResource.java file acting as the REST controller for this functionality. I have also created a PaymentService. When calling from the TypeScript file I call like this

> this.http.post(SERVER_API_URL + 'path/anotherpath',request);

This is my PaymentResource file

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/path")
public class PaymentResource {

private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PaymentResource.class);


public PaymentResource(){
}



@PostMapping("/anotherpath")
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
public void tokenize(@RequestBody String body) {

    log.logger("here");

   }
}
```

The string tokenize method never gets executed because I can not see the log.

Any help is appreciated it! 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was missing the subscribe on the component.ts:

```
this.paymentService.sendInfo().subscribe((response) => {
                    console.log(response.ok);
});
```

and an Observable on the service.ts file.